# "Кракозябры" при чтении сайта

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, requests

Читаем главную страницу сайта на русском языке, с кодировкой `UTF-8`:

```py
import requests


url = 'http://kasta.ua'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'
}
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

with open('test.html', 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.text.encode('UTF8'))
```

В выходном файле "кракозябры". Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Вы открываете файл в 'wb' моде и он ожидает данные в бинарном виде.

`r.text` это строковые данные, когда `r.content` это собственно бинарная информация.

Так же метод `.encoding` возвращает кодировку ответа.

Попробуйте

```
with open('test.html', 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Ошибка: ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument

Comment: with open('test.html', 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.content)

Comment: Исправьте на без указания кодировки.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka без кодировки сработало?

Comment: Сработало, спасибо.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka Рад, если смог помочь :)

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka Если один из ответов помог, пожалуйста, примите его)

Answer (score 1):

Кодировка возвращаемого `HTML` на самом деле `ISO-8859-1`. Перед записью Вам необходимо перекодировать его в `UTF-8`.

***Пример:***

```py
import requests


URL = 'http://kasta.ua/'

def main():
    html = requests.get(URL).text.encode('ISO-8859-1').decode('UTF-8')
    with open('test.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(html)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Кодировка возвращаемого HTML на самом деле ISO-8859-1 - это всегда так или вы посмотрели на сайте? У меня в браузере в исходном коде Utf-8.

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u22c6' in position 53: character maps to <undefined>